# In Keynote, how can I simulate magic move between different images?

Tags: keynote, animation

I have two similar images that represent the same thing (a happy and sad face for a particular character). I use magic move for most slide transitions in my presentation, but obviously that doesn't work for the different images. Is it possible to tell Keynote that the images should be related somehow? If not, what's the best way to "fake" the magic move for these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you want **both** objects on **both** slides, **overlapping**, then animate the **opacity** between the two with Magic Move. This recreates a Magic Move pretty accurately.

[image]

See [Keynote Magic Move between two different objects](https://georgegarside.com/blog/keynote-magic-move-two-different-objects/)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had the images in the right places, but hadn't thought to have them on the original slide with no opacity. Thanks for the post :)